# Swift 3 | Parse | PFQueryArrayResultBlock error, expected argument type '([PFObject]?, Error?) -> Void?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Recently converted from Swift 2 to Swift 3 in XCode 8. Using Parse SDK 1.14

Code:

```
    static func allUsers(completionBlock: @escaping PFQueryArrayResultBlock) -> PFQuery<PFObject> {

    let query = PFUser.query()!
    // exclude the current user
    query.whereKey(ParseHelper.ParseUserUsername,
        notEqualTo: PFUser.current()!.username!)
    query.order(byAscending: ParseHelper.ParseUserUsername)
    query.limit = 20

    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: completionBlock)

    return query
}
```

Error is showing at completionBlock in query.findObjectsInBackground(block: completionBlock)

The error reads:
Cannot covert value of type '([PFGenericObject]?, Error?) -> Void' to expected argument type 
'([PFObject]?, Error?) -> Void?'

Looking at  PFQueryArrayResultBlock shows: 
`public typealias PFQueryArrayResultBlock = ([PFGenericObject]?, Error?) -> Swift.Void`

I'm not familiar with PFGenericObject, but what should I be putting into query.findObjectsInBackground as a completion block?
[here is a picture of the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMOdx.png)

Comment: Fixed it. Instead of using the PFQueryArrayResultBlock, use: `static func allUsers(completionBlock: @escaping ([PFObject]?, Error?) -> Void) -> PFQuery<PFObject> { `